Will this resolve 'bubbling' noise coming from bathroom sink with A/C condensation drain line?
I've moved into a new home and have a lot of little chores to handle up on.  One of them is a 'bubbling' or 'popping' noise coming from an upstairs bathroom sink that occurs periodically when one of the A/C units is running.
My theory is that since the main drain line going into the wall is essentially level with where the condensate line taps into the drain that the water level in the Ptrap is inconsistent and sometimes results in bubbling of some sort.  I'm not a plumber or engineer.
However, my thought is that if I'm able to shorten the length of the metal drain pipe coming out of the sink, then I'll be able to push that intake adapter piece up a bit so that it is maybe 1" higher (it's as high up as I can get it currently) and therefore above the main drain line and the gurgling will stop.
Update:  Included a pic of the hvac drain line out.  Two units share this same main drain line and both have a similar series of 90deg bends at the hvac unit.
Thoughts?  Advice?



Take out the Y that the drain line attaches to. (red X)  Replace it with a straight tailpiece extender.
Put the Y in the horizontal line into the drain hub. (Yellow mark) You will need to get a longer hose.
Make sure the horizontal line has a tilt toward the wall. Then the condensation will run into the drain pipe and not into the P-trap.  Noise is eliminated.


If the condensate connection will be moved ahead of the existing P-trap then it'll need to be trapped separately here or at the other end, won't it?

@Greg Hill, good point.  I'm used to the ACs  in my area to have a trap right by the pan under the evap.  This may be different.  But a series of 90Deg. elbows could work.

Thanks for the information, I've updated with an image of the HVAC side of the condensate line to show a series of existing 90Deg. elbows.

@Kevin Hagen, thanks. that is what i expected, but I should not assume that is the case always.

Next time the wife heads out of town I'll dig in and implement the suggested modifications and report back.  Thanks!

OP could simply choke up on the threaded adapter at the sink tailpiece, or shorten the tailpiece.
